# key error 1 in my code, not sure what exactly needs editing

Tags: function

So this is my function here, tryna get some regression statistics based on the two data series below the function:

```
def ic_analysis2(infl, ls_portfolio, frequency='monthly'):
    
    #We load all the modules needed in the function just in case they are not loaded in the notebook.
    #They are only active within the function, if you need them elsewhere in the notebook you need to 
    #import them again in the notebook
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import stats
    
    #We check that the frequency is correct. If not we stop the function and return an empty result
    if frequency not in ['monthly', 'quarterly', 'annual']:
        print('Warning, the frequency must be monthly, quarterly or annual')
        return None
    
    #We capture the name of the factor using the .name attribute to use it later
    infl_name = infl.name
    
    #We calculate the returns according to the periodicity chosen in the input
    if frequency=='monthly':
        future_returns = np.log(ls_portfolio.groupby('date').shift(-1) / ls_portfolio).rename('fut_ret')
        
    elif frequency=='quarterly':
        future_returns = np.log(ls_portfolio.groupby('date').shift(-3) / ls_portfolio).rename('fut_ret')
        
    elif frequency=='annual':
        future_returns = np.log(ls_portfolio.groupby('date').shift(-12) / ls_portfolio).rename('fut_ret')
    
        
    #We join the signal with the future return
    data = infl.to_frame().join(future_returns).dropna()
    data['month'] = data.index.get_level_values('date').month
    
    #We select the relevant months for the annual or quarterly analysis
    if frequency=='annual':
        data = data[data['month']==12]
        
    elif frequency=='quarterly':
        data = data[data['month'].isin([3, 6, 9, 12])] #.isin() checks if the number is among the ones in the list
    
    #We drop the month column because we do not need it anymore
    data.drop(columns=['month'], inplace=True)
    
    #We calculate the IC
    ic = data.groupby('date').corr(method='spearman').iloc[0::2,-1].rename('IC')
    
    #We print on screen the average IC
    print('Average IC:', round(ic.mean(), 3), '\n')
    
    #We calculate and print the percentage of positive/negative observations
    sign = np.sign(ic).value_counts() / ic.count()
    
    print('Percentage of Positive Periods:', round(sign.loc[1], 3), '\n')
    print('Percentage of Negative Periods:', round(sign.loc[-1], 3), '\n')
    
    #We calculate and print the t-test
    t_test = stats.ttest_1samp(ic, 0)
    print(f'T-Stat: {round(t_test.statistic,3)} P-Value: {round(t_test.pvalue,3)} \n')
    
    #We return the series with the Information Coefficient for further analysis using the original name of the factor
    return ic.rename('IC_' + infl_name)
```

These are the series being used:

```
infl = 

date
1996-01-31    2.95597
1996-02-29    2.88582
1996-03-29    2.81426
1996-04-30    2.61845
1996-05-31    2.67579
Name: INFL, dtype: float64

ls_portfolio = 

date
1996-01-31   -0.003283
1996-02-29    0.010023
1996-03-29    0.004916
1996-04-30    0.001046
1996-05-31    0.004154
Name: LS Portfolio, dtype: float64
```

and this is the error code, which I haven't been able to decipher. Originally the code used different series and I was able to alter a few elements to fit the new series but I'm stuck at this point:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1.0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/7w/cp1r7vy90rd_bw_2p759mnyw0000gn/T/ipykernel_55426/1018484474.py in <module>
----> 1 ic_infl = ap.ic_analysis2(infl, ls_portfolio, frequency='monthly')

~/Downloads/apmodule.py in ic_analysis2(infl, ls_portfolio, frequency)
    552     sign = np.sign(ic).value_counts() / ic.count()
    553 
--> 554     print('Percentage of Positive Periods:', round(sign.loc[1], 3), '\n')
    555     print('Percentage of Negative Periods:', round(sign.loc[-1], 3), '\n')
    556 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    965 
    966             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 967             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    968 
    969     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: tuple):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1203         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1204         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1205         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1206 
   1207     def _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj: slice, axis: int):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
   1151     def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1152         # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1153         return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
   1154 
   1155     def _handle_lowerdim_multi_index_axis0(self, tup: tuple):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3862                     new_index = index[loc]
   3863         else:
-> 3864             loc = index.get_loc(key)
   3865 
   3866             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:
-> 3631                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 1
```

Originally I had a bunch of other errors, which I was able to fix, but this one has stumped me